# Transform from SolrDocument to class

Tags: java, solr

I need to convert data retrieved from Solr to specific class, I've tried 3 different ways, but each of them has some problem.

*Method 1 : using 3rd party library - JSONUtil.*

```
    SolrDocument solrDocument = (SolrDocument) iterator.next();
    String jsonString = JSONUtil.toJSON(solrDocument);
    EventObject eventObject2 = gson.fromJson(jsonString, EventObject.class);
```

*Method 2 : transform solrDocument to JsonString directly.*

```
    String jsonString2 = gson.toJson(solrDocument);
    EventObject eventObject3 = gson.fromJson(jsonString2, EventObject.class);
```

*Method 3 : transform solrDocument to JSONObject then convert to JsonString.*

```
    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(solrDocument);
    String jsonStringFromJsonObject = object.toString();
    EventObject eventObjectFromJsonObject = gson.fromJson(jsonStringFromJsonObject, EventObject.class);
```

*Method 4 : using Java Beans*

```
    List<EventObject> EventObjects = response.getBeans(EventObject.class);
```

The result of *Method1* can't handle fields which is *Date* or *ArrayList* Type. The result of *Method2*, *Method3* and *Method4* are all the same, they handle all fields well, however, *ArrayList* field are still empty.

### **Edit :**

My Solr schema is as follows(only mention the 2 fields which can't transform correctly) :

```
<dynamicField name="*_Image_Infos" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" multiValued="true" />
<dynamicField name="*_ss" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" multiValued="true" />
```

My EventObject is as follows :

```
public List<EventObjectImageInfo> ImageInfos = new ArrayList<EventObjectImageInfo>();
public List<EventObjectColor> Colors = new ArrayList<EventObjectColor>();
```

Both of *EventObjectImageInfo* & *EventObjectColor* are my own classes.

---

Did I do anything wrong? Or is there any other way should I try? Thanks!

Comment: USE solr JavaBeans

Comment: http://opensourceconnections.com/blog/2016/01/11/java_beans_and_solrj_and_realtime_get_oh_my/

Comment: @AshrafulIslam Thanks for your advice! I tried that way but it still can't handle those "ArrayList" type field, they are still empty after transform. However, you provide another way to convert data from Solr to class, still appreciate!

Comment: Show your solr schema and EventObject class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You can use Solr JavaBeans**

Let's say i have the solr schema :

```
<field name="id" type="string" multiValued="false" indexed="true" required="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="name" type="string" indexed="false" stored="true"/>
<field name="marks" type="long" multiValued="true" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

I have the Student class

```
public class Student {
    @Field
    String id;

    @Field
    String name;

    @Field
    ArrayList<Long> marks;
}
```

Now I can convert SolrDocumentList to List with javabeans

```
SolrDocumentList list; // you already have that
DocumentObjectBinder binder = new DocumentObjectBinder();
List<Student> dataList = binder.getBeans(Student.class, list);
```

Comment: Thanks! This method works like a charm. That could parse ArrayList fields correctly. The problem is caused by type mis-match in my program before. And very sorry for responding to your answer so late!